# I need to return text of clicks

Tags: jquery

I need to return text of all click that I made, after this I will send some of them in data layer, but can't do it. Help please

```
$("*").click(

    function () {
        {
            var s_name = jQuery(this).find("*").html();
            return s_name;
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: sorry,* I need to return text of clicks*

Comment: Please format the code

Answer (score 1):

Is this you wanted? `$(this).text()` this will return text of the element.

```js
$("button").click(function () {
  {
    var s_name = $(this).text();
    console.log(s_name);
  }
}
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>HELLO</button>
<button>WELCOME</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "*" selector which is an "all selector".

```
$("*").click(function(){
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

Here's an example

```js
$("*").click(function(){

alert($(this).text());

});
```

```css
div{
width:50px;
height:50px;
background:pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Hello</div>
<button>Click me</button>
```